# Webpack with Thridparty bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack, vendor

i want to provide a webpack bundle which contains all common thirdparty vendors(angular 1.4, jQuery, and some other libs).

Currently the follow modules are developed

- Module A
- Vendor Module

## Vendor Module:

Create a simple module with all thridparty libs(angular 1.4, jQuery, and some other libs)

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
        entry: {
            vendor: './index.js',
        },
        output: {
            // filename: '[chunkhash].[name].js',
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        plugins: []
    }
```

**index.js:**

```
require('jquery');
require('angular');
```

## Module A:

**index.js:**

```
var angular = require('angular');
var myJQ = require('jQuery');
var app = angular.module("Test", []);

console.log("Angular Boostrap");
console.log(app);
console.log("jQuery Boostrap");
console.log(myJQ);
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
        entry: {
            main: './index.js',
        },
        externals: {
            angular: 'angular',
            "jQuery": {
                root: '$',
                commonjs: 'jquery',
                amd: 'jquery'
            }
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        plugins: []
    }
```

Module A index.js can require 'angular' and i see the right output, but the require from 'jquery' failed with an error.

There a two questions in my mind.

1. Which is common way to include third party vendors?
2. Whats wrong with jquery in the Module A index.js

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way to include third party vendors is the DllPlugin. It does exactly what you want, splitting your app in two bundles. That way the build process is fast, independent and you have no limits in your app, because the dllPlugin connects both bundles. Sadly, there is no documentation about the dllPlugin in the webpack v2 documentation yet, but there are tutorials around, like https://robertknight.me.uk/posts/webpack-dll-plugins/
2. I think it depends on which jQuery you use. If jQuery exposes itself onto the window automatically, try

   ```
   externals: { jQuery: 'window.jQuery' }
   ```